# Core Data returns Null when i save

Tags: iphone, core-data

here is my code,

`hand` is the entity, and `addRounds` is a textField

```
-(IBAction)save{

[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
[self.hand setValue:self.addRounds.text forKey:@"rounds"];
    NSError *error;
    if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
            //Handle Error
    }
NSLog(@"%@", self.addRounds.text);
NSLog(@"%@", self.hand.rounds);
```

}

the console out puts

```
2012-11-25 16:51:18.847 App[3187:c07] 1
2012-11-25 16:51:18.848 App[3187:c07] (null)
```

so, for some reason, its not saving properly. Could anyone please help me! Thank You!

```
-(IBAction)save{

if (self.managedObjectContext == nil)
{
    self.managedObjectContext = [(RootAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext];
}


    Hand *hand = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Hand" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    hand.rounds = nil;
    self.managedObjectContext = self.app.managedObjectContext;

    NSError *error;

    if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
         //Handle Error
    }
```

}

***Edit***

So Basically There is a total of 4 Views. 
1) view with Table view, user can press '+' button
2) This view allows the user to add a cell to the table view
3) allows the user to `edit` the table view cells
4) this is a completely different view that also allows the user to edit the table view cells.

I'm using the code at the top of the question to save in both views `3 & 4`. It works perfectly in view 3 but not 4!!

***UPDATE!!!***

So, I recoded the app so that views 1 & 4 are the only two views in the app. When i `push` view 2 and view 3 in between view 1 and 4 it sets my managedObjectContext's `rounds` attribute to `null`.

Comment: You might want to log the error object to see what the error is.

Comment: @sosborn i did this, and there is no error. It just keeps returning `null`

Answer (score 1):

Is the rounds attribute of your hand entity a string in your model?

First, you should set the type on your hand entity's rounds attribute to a number type. 16bit integer would probably suffice (we're talking about a card game, right?), but you could make it bigger if you like.

Next change your code to:

```
-(IBAction)save{
NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
NSNumber *rounds = [numberFormatter numberFromString:numberself.addRounds.text];

[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
[self.hand setValue:rounds forKey:@"rounds"];
    NSError *error;
    if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
            //Handle Error
    }
NSLog(@"%@", self.addRounds.text);
NSLog(@"%@", self.hand.rounds);
```

Also, I'm assuming you've inserted the instance of hand that you're setting properties on somewhere before this point. Maybe I shouldn't assume. Have you already initialized this managed object instance, self.hand, to point to data in the store?

For example, I like to use lazy instantiation:

```
- (Hand*)hand
{
    if (_hand = nil) {
        _hand = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Hand" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    }
    return _hand;
}
```

This assumes a purely -create oriented- design. In most cases, you'd want to edit an existing object and update its rounds count. For this, you should attempt to retrieve a Hand that you're editing first. You'd do that with an NSFetchRequest, and there a zillions of examples of that, so I won't repeat them here. If There were no matches, this getter would create one as a fall-back. Also, best practice is to create a category for Hand (maybe Hand+Edit.m) which contains methods for retrieving different Hands, creating them, and updating common properties.

I'd create worker methods inside the Hand object category like these:

```
+ (void)incrementRoundsOnHand:(Hand *)hand withManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context
+ (void)incrementRoundsBy:(NSUInteger)count onHand:(Hand *)hand withManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context
// or some sort of unique identifier, date, number, etc
+ (Hand *)handWithName:(NSString *)name withManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context
```

I'd then have handWithName: (or whatever) do an NSFetchRequest, and if nothing matches, create a new hand and return it. Either way, you get a hand back. Important is that you don't deal with manipulating the specifics of your Hand entity outside of the Hand managed object class. Note, since these are class methods, they can be called directly.

Comment: hey bro, i tried this code, and unfortunately its doing the same thing, on the second `NSLog`, its returning `NULL`. :( ive done this a million times before. But this time is giving me a hard time! Thank you for the help!

Comment: Can you show the code where you initialize the managed object hand?

Comment: sure buddy, i added it to the question, above! Thank you for your time!

Comment: Sorry, have been a bit bogged down in work to get on and answer this. Basically, if you're getting NULL back it means either your ManagedObjectContext or your ManagedObject aren't initialized properly at some point. There are syntax errors in the update you posted, so it's difficult to step through your code. Set a break point on the line where you send the message to NSEntityDescription and look in the debugger to see if self.managedObjectContext is nil or not. If it is at that point, then you know what your problem is.